# Removing PropertyChanged-item from BindingList causes list to Reset

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, bindinglist, propertychanged

User defined class inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged.

In user defined class some property broadcasts PropertyChanged event.

During that event object itself is removed from BindingList.

Event continues execution and BindingList gets ListChangedType.Reset event.

What can be done to avoid Reset event ?

Answer (score 0):

(Haven't seen answer to this question, so decided to add both - question and answer)

Google for "BindingList Child_PropertyChanged"

gives following code snipet:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BindingList.cs,e757be5fba0e6000,references

Means that if event is received by BindingList, and given item is not in BindingList - it will trigger list reset.

But because PropertyChanged.Invoke collect whole list of events before starting to broadcast before execution - event will be invoked anyway independently of whether item is in list or not.

Let following code snipet to demonstrate error:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;

namespace Eventing
{

    public class ThisItem : MulticastNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        void Test()
        {
        }

        String _name;
        public String name2
        {
            get {
                return _name;
            }

            set
            {
                _name = value;

                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Invoke test #2");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
                Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("name"));
            }
        }

        public String name1
        {
            get {
                return _name;
            }

            set
            {
                _name = value;
#if TESTINVOKE
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Invoke test #1");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
                InvokeFast(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("name"));
#endif
            }
        }
    };

    class Program
    {
        static public BindingList<ThisItem> testList;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testList = new BindingList<ThisItem>();
            ThisItem t = new ThisItem();
            testList.ListChanged += testList_ListChanged;

            t.PropertyChanged += t_PropertyChanged;
            t.PropertyChanged += t_PropertyChanged2;
            testList.Add(t);
            t.name1 = "testing";

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
            t.PropertyChanged -= t_PropertyChanged;
            t.PropertyChanged -= t_PropertyChanged2;
            t.PropertyChanged += t_PropertyChanged;
            testList.Add(t);
            t.PropertyChanged += t_PropertyChanged2;

            t.name2 = "testing";
        }

        static void testList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3) List changed: " + e.ListChangedType.ToString() + ((e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.Reset) ? " (*** UPS! ***)": ""));
        }

        static void t_PropertyChanged2(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2) t_PropertyChanged2: " + e.PropertyName);
        }

        static void t_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1) t_PropertyChanged: " + e.PropertyName);
            testList.Remove((ThisItem)sender);
        }
    }
}
```

MulticastNotifyPropertyChanged.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace System
{
    /// <summary>
    /// class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged in such manner that event can be broadcasted in safe manner - 
    /// even if given item is removed from BindingList, event in BindingList (Child_PropertyChanged) won't be 
    /// triggered.
    /// </summary>
    public class MulticastNotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// List of all registered events. List can change during event broadcasting.
        /// </summary>
        List<PropertyChangedEventHandler> _PropertyChangedHandlers = new List<PropertyChangedEventHandler>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Next broadcasted event index.
        /// </summary>
        int iFuncToInvoke;
    #if TESTINVOKE
            PropertyChangedEventHandler _PropertyChangedAllInOne;
    #endif

        event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
        {
            add
            {
    #if TESTINVOKE
                    _PropertyChangedAllInOne += value;
    #endif
                _PropertyChangedHandlers.Add(value);
            }
            remove
            {
    #if TESTINVOKE
                    _PropertyChangedAllInOne -= value;
    #endif
                int index = _PropertyChangedHandlers.IndexOf(value);

                if (index == -1)
                    return;

                if (iFuncToInvoke >= index)     //Scroll back event iterator if needed.
                    iFuncToInvoke--;

    #if TESTINVOKE
                    Console.WriteLine("Unregistering event. Iterator value: " + iFuncToInvoke.ToString());
    #endif
                _PropertyChangedHandlers.Remove(value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Just an accessor, so no cast would be required on client side.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
        {
            add
            {
                ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this).PropertyChanged += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this).PropertyChanged -= value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Same as normal Invoke, except this plays out safe - if item is removed from BindingList during event broadcast -
        /// event won't be fired in removed item direction.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void Invoke(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (iFuncToInvoke = 0; iFuncToInvoke < _PropertyChangedHandlers.Count; iFuncToInvoke++)
            {
    #if TESTINVOKE
                    Console.WriteLine("Invoke: " + iFuncToInvoke.ToString());
    #endif
                _PropertyChangedHandlers[iFuncToInvoke].Invoke(sender, e);
            }
        }

    #if TESTINVOKE
            public void InvokeFast( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e )
            {
                _PropertyChangedAllInOne.Invoke(sender, e);
            }
    #endif
    }

} //namespace System
```

Will result in following execution flow:

```
3) List changed: ItemAdded
---------------------------
Invoke test #1
---------------------------
1) t_PropertyChanged: name
Unregistering event. Iterator value: 0
3) List changed: ItemDeleted
2) t_PropertyChanged2: name
3) List changed: Reset (*** UPS! ***)
---------------------------
Unregistering event. Iterator value: -1
Unregistering event. Iterator value: -1
3) List changed: ItemAdded
---------------------------
Invoke test #2
---------------------------
Invoke: 0
1) t_PropertyChanged: name
Unregistering event. Iterator value: 0
3) List changed: ItemDeleted
Invoke: 1
2) t_PropertyChanged2: name
```

This solved list eventing - however it can create more problems with items adding to BindingList durign event. This code can probably we fixed also to not to broadcast events to newly added items (like normal BindingList does), but this is something you can work out on your own if needed.